# Toilet leaking into bowl

Tags: leak, toilet

We had a HydroRight in the toilet for several years (with the split, dual flush handle) and all of a sudden, water began trickling into the bowl, and the tank would refill every 10-15 minutes, which would take just a few seconds.

I thought maybe there was a rebuild kit for the HydroRight so I could replace some seals, but didn't find one. So, instead I bought all new internals, but this time a Fluidmaster Dual Flush. This one came with the angled adapter to change the bottom mounting point of the overflow tube from an angle to being level, onto which the complex flushing mechanism fit.

The toilet still had the same problem. It seemed to me that the leak must have been where the flushing mechanism attaches to bottom of the overflow tube. The new one attached via what I believe is plumber's putty. I thought maybe I hadn't cleaned the ring adequately where contact occurs or maybe didn't dry it well enough, so I took it apart, and threw away the putty that came with the Fluidmaster. I bought new plumber's putty (which is a very different consistency from what came on the Fluidmaster adapter), rolled it out, and, after cleaning the adapter and the contact point at the bottom (where the flapper would normally touch) very thoroughly and letting them dry, applied the putty to the adapter, then pushed it firmly into place. Then, I shoved the Fluidmaster flushing mechanism back into place on top of that adapter.

Just to be clear, when I cleaned the contact point at the bottom of the overflow tube, I observed that it appeared to be smooth, undamaged, and in perfect shape. I would've expected a good seal.

Still leaks. No idea what to try next. Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing a running toilet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78468/fixing-a-running-toilet)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Replace the that part little plastic connected to the chain

Comment: To clarify, this is called your "flapper valve" and is the thing that PREVENTS the water in the tank from draining down into the bowl. Pushing the handle lifts that valve to dump the water down, but in your case that flapper is leaking. They get old and the rubber starts to deteriorate, especially if you use chlorine tablets in the tank for trying to keep the bowl clean. This hads nothing to do with the FILL VALVE which is/was your Hydroright or Fluidmaster. You probably didn't need to replace that...

Answer (score 0):

If tank water is leaking down into the bowl, the flapper ball isn't sealing in its seat.